# New to rvest package - trying to scrape a basic table from a webpage using R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm just trying to scrape the first table at this link (titled "Standings - Points"): https://www.fantrax.com/fantasy/league/vu0zoow2kk7bh64k/standings

In following some documentation and previous posts on here, I've tried:

```
data <- read_html("https://www.fantrax.com/fantasy/league/vu0zoow2kk7bh64k/standings")
tables <- data %>% html_table(fill = TRUE)
```

and

```
data <- read_html("https://www.fantrax.com/fantasy/league/vu0zoow2kk7bh64k/standings")
tables <- html_nodes(data, "table")
```

neither were able to pick anything up from that page - R is just showing a blank return for each. I'm hoping/guessing it's just something simple that I'm missing.

Comment: There are no tables in the source code of that page. Note that `rvest` will only look at the HTML source code. It cannot run any javascript on that page. Most modern websites use javascript to load data after the HTML loads. You can see what rvest sees if you inspect the "Sources" tab, not the "Elements" tab of your developer tools. The Elements are what is there after javascript runs. If you need to pull data from sites that use javascript, consider using RSelenium instead. Or you can comb through the network tab to see if you can find where the data is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Using `RSelenium`

```
library(RSelenium)
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)

# Launching the browser
rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=4551L, verbose=F)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]  
url = 'https://www.fantrax.com/fantasy/league/vu0zoow2kk7bh64k/standings'
remDr$navigate(url)
# Extracting tables
remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
  read_html() %>%
  html_table()
```